# GUI text is moving along with the player

Tags: user-interface, game-maker, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

The video attached shows the issue, the code controlling the ammo count, and the viewport/camera properties. I would like the ammo count to stay in place, rather than moving with oPlayer.

I'm new to Game-maker and game development in general, this is my first time trying to make a GUI, so issues in my code/room setup are to be expected.

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Video: https://youtu.be/38jZSsAxHh0

Code:

```
var vc = view_camera[0];

var cx = camera_get_view_x(vc);

var cy = camera_get_view_y(vc);

var cw = camera_get_view_width(vc);


draw_set_colour($000000);

draw_text(cx + (cw / 10),cy + 32, string(ARmaxclipammo) + string("/") + string(ARmaxammo));
```

Comment: I remember that I was facing the same problem, The position of the GUI is moving along with the position of the camera. if I remember correctly, you just need to set `x` instead of `camera_get_view_x(vc)`. But I need to recheck that at my own project when I'm home before I can post it as an answer. At least you can try it out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of your text is set equall with the position of the camera. So if the camera moves in the room, The text will move across the screen as well.

You don't need to set the text position to follow the camera, because `DrawGUI` already allows that. All you need to do is to show the specific position of the text where you want to show it on screen.

So, as example in your code:

```
var cx = 50;
var cy = 50;
```

Will show it in the position of (50x, 50y), and `DrawGUI` already let it follow the camera.